# .switchClass on .$("#xxx").hover: how can I stop the transition when the mouse leave #xxx?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I have this simple SCRIPT (http://jsfiddle.net/ibundi/mu7BG/): some switchClass of DIVs from

```
.main{width:x;height:y;line-height:z;}
```

to

```
.h(eight) or .w(idth) {width:XX;heigth:YY;line-height:z;}.
```

Now I want to prevent weird queue of transition,

```
return false;
```

doesn't work, like as

```
.stop(1,0).switchClass ...
```

Now,
1)How can I stop weird queueing?
2)How can I stop the transition when the mouse leave the hover element, without wait the entire transition from old class to new-class?

I'm using 1.8.16 ver of JqueryUI.
Thx for your attention.
L

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle with the issue?

Comment: @j08691 here I am, sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow & jsField.Here the code <http://jsfiddle.net/ibundi/mu7BG/>

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the second function you supply to hover() is being fired when it shouldn't? Like when you are still 'inside' the element, but have just hovered on another element *inside* of it?

If so, instead of `hover()` use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

Comment: From the jQuery docs: The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: ah >< must have changed at some point, used to use mouseover and mouseout

Comment: I would like to begin the transition on "mouseout" without having finished "mousein" animation from width and heigth of class A to B, and make that prevent weird queuing...